# Does changing a post title of a published post automatically change permalink?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, title

In what I’ve seen and what i’ve read, changing a title to a published post won’t change the permalink. I researched again this morning and found nothing to contradict that.

However, a client changed a published post’s title, several actually, and has broken links. In looking at the editor, the permalink had in fact changed.

I fixed it by editing the permalink back to the original, keeping the updated title.

Site uses Divi and Yoast, if that’s relevant.

What is the truth here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it. Looks like the client also changed the permalink. Remember when you click on "Edit" in the permalink and write some text and then click OK Wordpress will convert that link into a permalink.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I agree. That’s what my experiments show. I was just wondering if I were crazy.

Comment: No, but maybe your client wanted to take you for a ride

Comment: I think she must be confusing the title and permalink or something.